# Beautiful Soup Returns Tags and Text

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape college football recruit data from ESPN's website.  I have figured out how to scrape all of the TD tags that I need, but my output keeps returning the tags and everything in them with the actual text that they enclose.

I've been through an hours worth of questions on the website and I understand that either the .text or .string should fix this problem, but neither seem to be working. It's possible I'm putting them in the wrong places.

Here is the code that I'm running:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen

f = open("17athletes.txt", 'w')

sock = urlopen("http://espn.go.com/college-sports/football/recruiting/playerrankings/_/position/athlete/class/2017/view/position")
html = sock.read()
sock.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup (html, "lxml")
for tr in soup.findAll("tr"):
    tds = str(tr.find_all("td"))
    f.write(tds)

f.close()
```

And this is a small part of what it's returning:

```
    <td width="3%">RK</td>, <td width="25%">PLAYER</td>, <td width="6%">POS</td>
```

I'm wondering if the problem is where I put the `str()` in the code?  Or I'm wondering if because ESPN is such a complex site there might be something else I need to do.  I'm extremely new to all this, but I'm trying my best to learn the correct way.  Using BeautifulSoup 2.4 and Python 2.7 if that helps. Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"..but neither seem to be working"* Not working in what way?

Comment: When I try either, I still seem to get both the tag and the text inside instead of just the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should loop through all the `td`s you find as well. Your code should look like this

```
for tr in soup.find_all("tr"):
    for td in tr.find_all("td")
        f.write(td.text)
```

Comment: Ah!  Thank you, I'll try that when I get home.

Comment: Had to replace "string" with "text" for some reason, but otherwise works perfectly!  If anyone else wants to use this in the future, i found that making the last line   f.write(td.text + ",") produces a text file that is very easy to convert using text-to-columns in Excel.